# Angular display error message from reactive form in html template

Tags: angular, reactive

Is it possible to display validators error message inside html template
I have something like this

```
this.formBuilder.group({
 sizeOfBuildingPart: [{ value: 0, disabled:false }, [Validators.min(0),Validators.max(100), Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[0-9]*$')]]});
```

In html template I need to display error message if max value is bigger then validators

Something like this

```
 {{formControls.sizeOfBuildingPart.errors?.max}}
```

It is working ok, but is it possible to display what is max number value (in this case 100), tried something like this

```
{{formControls.sizeOfBuildingPart.errors?.max.value}}
```

But it does not work, thanks in advance

Comment: You need to check the [documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators#max). If error, It returns nul, if not it retuns an object which has `max` and `actual`properties, so you need to reach it like `formControls.sizeOfBuildingPart.errors?.max.max` or `formControls.sizeOfBuildingPart.errors?.max.actual`

Comment: formControls.sizeOfBuildingPart.errors?.max.max , thanks, can you write an answer that I can accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use : (form.controls['sizeOfBuildingPart'].errors?.max?.max)
That will return you max number provided in validations.

Here is working demo for it:
[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-k8pmyp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)